# Add up all values from objects in array but multiplied with quantity

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I wanna create logic for my app that have Cart. So when user clicks on Cart can see items that are in there and can see total price. What I have is hook that stores all objects inside and looks like this:

```
[{
foodName: "Njoki with sos"
foodPrice: 35
numberOfPortions: 1
}, 
{
foodName: "Chicken Wingos"
foodPrice: 45
numberOfPortions: 2
}]
```

I created logic that looks like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    cartFood.map((food) => {
      return priceArray.push(food.foodPrice * food.numberOfPortions);
    });
  }, [cartFood]);

  let priceArray = [];

  let cartTotalPrice = priceArray.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
```

But it is not working, cartTotal price is 0 even tho it should be 125 and also I get notification from React in compiler "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'priceArray'. Either include it or remove the dependency array" so I guess there is better way to do it...
What did I do wrong and what is the best way to writte this logic?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you're not interested in the return value of `Array.prototype.map()` then `.map()` is not the right tool to use.

Comment: @Andreas Hi,  I also tried with forEach() but same result, 0

Comment: `var total = [/*yourarray*/].reduce(function(acc, cur) { return acc + cur.foodPrice * cur.numberOfPortions; }, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use either of the methods to loop over your array and get the total price

### forEach

```
let totalPrice = 0;

values.forEach(value => {
  totalPrice += value.foodPrice * value.numberOfPortions;
});
```

### for loop

```
let totalPrice = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  totalPrice += values[i].foodPrice * values[i].numberOfPortions;
}
```

### for-of loop

```
let totalPrice = 0;

for (let value of values) {
  totalPrice += value.foodPrice * value.numberOfPortions;
}
```

### reduce

```
const totalPrice = values.reduce(
  (acc, cur) => acc + cur.foodPrice * cur.numberOfPortions,
  0
);
```